# List all daemon/service names in linux using Python?

Tags: python, linux, daemon

I want to have list of all daemons/services in Linux using python.
I am able to get information using

```
service --status-all
```

However I don't want to execute terminal commands through Python. Is there any API available to perform this operation?

My project includes lots of stuff so I need to be careful with memory and cpu usage, also I may need to run the command every 10sec or 60sec depending on configuration.
So I don't want to create too many process.

Earlier I had used **subprocess.check_output(command)**

But I was told by my manager to avoid using commands and try to use any available packages, I tried searching some but could found packages which can only monitor services and cannot list.

Finally my objective is to minimize load on system.
Any suggestions ?

Additoinal details-

```
Python 3.7.2
Ubuntu 16
```

Comment: `service` is a legacy command. Modern systems (including Ubuntu 16 AFAIK) use `systemd`.  To monitor try: `systemctl -a -t service` or similar. I don't think there is anything wrong with running `systemctl` as a subprocess.

Comment: Well I need to run every 5sec or max 10sec, subprocess will put lot of strain on cpu and memory  as it will create too many process and kill many..

Comment: Why do you need to check everything every 5 or so seconds? And how will you handle failures? `systemd` can restart services or send notifications automatically (just learn how to configure services), isn't that all you need?

Comment: @VPfB I have to monitor linux metrics every 10 sec so services are part of it, though it may not be all but even if I have to monitor couple of services I don't want to create new process every time I check service status so I was looking for some solution which can get me result without calling terminal in python which actually creates sub-process.

Comment: Take a look at  Linux `/proc` filesystem. All processes are listed there one per directory (name = PID) with all the details.

Answer (score 0):

With psutil (sudo pip3 install psutil)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import psutil


def show_services():
    return [(
        psutil.Process(p).name(),
        psutil.Process(p).status(),
        )  for p in psutil.pids()]


def main():
    for service in show_services():
        if service[1] == 'running':
            print(service[0])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

show_services returns a list of tuples (name, status)

Comment: Its showing all process names and value seems strange, its showing sleeping and idle while many of services are active and running..

Comment: edit my answer to only show names of 'running' processes. Thanks @gadhvi

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a package for that, [pystemd](https://pypi.org/project/pystemd/).
   Quoting its front page:

> This library allows you to talk to systemd over dbus from python, without actually thinking that you are talking to systemd over dbus. This allows you to programmatically start/stop/restart/kill and verify services status from systemd point of view, avoiding executing subprocess.Popen(['systemctl', ... and then parsing the output to know the result.

so

```
pip install pystemd
```

and

```
from pystemd.systemd1 import Manager
manager = Manager()
manager.load()

print(manager.Manager.ListUnitFiles())
```

2. For efficiency, you don't need to reload list of services each time, if it hasn't changed. I don't have a right solution for that in my head, but I guess you could watch unit files directories with [inotify](https://pypi.org/project/inotify/) for example and only reload when they're changed.